# min and max tag is not showing in chart chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

the min and max attributes of chart.js are not working in the chart but the function next to the min and max statement is working properly
I have checked all the websites and all the issues but can't find the solution for that.please help

```
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,25,0,300);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(149, 76, 233, 0.5)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.35, "rgba(149, 76, 233, 0.25)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(149, 76, 233, 0)");
const revenue = [30.0, 38.2, 45.1, 52.4, 58.9, 65.2, 69.8, 71.6, 75.6, 82.2];
const labels = [
  "2010",
  "2011",
  "2012",
  "2013",
  "2014",
  "2015",
  "2016",
  "2017",
  "2018",
  "2019",
  "2020",
  "2021",
  "2022",
];
const data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            data: revenue,
            label: "Annual Revenue",
            fill: true, 
            backgroundColor: gradient,
            borderColor: "rgba(149, 76, 233, 1)",
            lineTension: 0.2,
            pointRadius: 3,
            borderWidth: 2,
        },
    ],
};
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        resposive: true,
        scales: {
            y:{
                grindLines:{
                    color: "rgba(149, 76, 233, 1)"
                },
                ticks:{
                    beginAtZero: false,
                    max : "10",
                    min : "100",
                    callback: function (value){
                        return "$" + value + "k";
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Chart.js version 3, `min` and `max` are of type `number` and they're no longer defined inside the `ticks` option but directly within the `scale` as follows:

```
scales: {
  y: { 
    min: 10,
    max: 100
  } 
  ...
```

I also noticed that in your code, `min` is bigger than `max`, this may have to be corrected.

> Please take a look at the Chart.js documentation [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#common-options-to-all-axes).